# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement'

Tags: jquery, arrays, video, parseint

I am working with Cuepoint.js to create text links that cue HTML5 video to a time marker corresponding with particular lines of text. I need to dynamically assign the links a time value already written to an array as a string. I know I need to use parseInt() to recast the values as integers when they are retrieved from the array. Since the links and their times are dynamic, I also need to assign the links their times within a for loop where they are then pushed to another array. Here's the code

```
    var cueTimes = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < textItems.length; j++) {
        var times = parseInt(timeItems[j]);
        cueTimes.push(times);
        $(".field-name-field-text-"+(j+1)+" > div > div").click(function(){ cuepoint.setTime(cueTimes[j])});
    console.log(cueTimes[j]);
    }
```

When I run the code, however, I receive this error.

***Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided double value is non-finite.***

As far as I can tell, the integer isn't being correctly read as such by jQuery. However, when I output the time values to my console, they appear as integers. When I test the code using a static array index  (for example setting cueTimes[0]), the code runs and works as expected.

Any suggestions on how to fix/work around this greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is the line from the Cuepoint.jS file that prompts the error:

```
Cuepoint.prototype.setTime = function(time) {
        this.time = time;
        this.video.currentTime = time;
        return this.video.play();
    };
```

Cuepoint.js code:

```
(function() {
/* Cuepoint Coffee. A simple library for HTML5 Video Subtitles and Cuepoints */

/**
 * @class Utils 
*/

var Cuepoint, Utils, utils;
Utils = (function() {
    function Utils() {}
    Utils.prototype.log = function(args) {
        this.args = args;
        if (window.console) {
            return console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(this, arguments));
        }
    };
    return Utils;
})();

/**
 * @class Cuepoint
 */

Cuepoint = (function() {
    function Cuepoint() {
        this.nativeKeys = Object.keys;
    }
    Cuepoint.prototype.init = function(slides) {
        var key, value, _results;
        this.slides = slides;
        this.subtitles = document.getElementById("subtitles");
        this.video = document.getElementById("video");
        _results = [];
        for (key in slides) {
            value = slides[key];
            this.addSlide(key, value);
            _results.push(this.events.call);
        }
        return _results;
    };
    Cuepoint.prototype.events = function() {};
    Cuepoint.prototype.currentTime = function() {
        return this.video.currentTime;
    };
    Cuepoint.prototype.update = function(html) {
        this.html = html;
        return this.subtitles.innerHTML = this.html;
    };
    Cuepoint.prototype.setTime = function(time) {
        this.time = time;
        this.video.currentTime = time;
        return this.video.play();
    };
    Cuepoint.prototype.addSlide = function(time, html) {
        var self;
        this.time = time;
        this.html = html;
        self = this;
        return this.video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
            if (this.currentTime >= time && this.currentTime <= time + 0.3) {
                return self.update(html);
            }
        },
        false);
    };
    Cuepoint.prototype.play = function() {
        return this.video.play();
    };
    Cuepoint.prototype.pause = function() {
        if (!this.video.paused) {
            return this.video.pause();
        }
    };
    return Cuepoint;
})();
utils = new Utils;
window.cuepoint = new Cuepoint;
```

}).call(this);

Comment: no mention of currentTime here, just 'time', which is different. Could you post a fiddle or at least some html and more of the jquery?

Comment: Sure, here's the Cuepoint.js code, where the error occurs - adding to my original post.

Comment: hmm.. still no html, can't reproduce problem with just javascript... you can make a fidde on http://www.jsfiddle.net or http://www.jsbin.com

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The closure of the click() function was causing the value of the iterator variable to be lost within that function. I solved it by creating a self-executing function to access the variable locally, explained here:

This code gets it done:

```
for(var j = 0; j< textItems.length; j++){
            (function(k){
            text[k] = parseInt(timeItems[k]);
            $(".field-name-field-text-"+(k+1)+" > div > div").click(function(){ cuepoint.setTime(text[k])});
        })(j);  
        }
```